# Transferring cash ISA to S&S LISA

Tags: united-kingdom, isa

I currently have a fixed cash ISA which matures tomorrow. I also have a stocks and shares (S&S) ISA and a cash help to buy ISA, both of which I have paid into this tax year. I'm thinking about transferring my maturing ISA into a S&S Lifetime ISA but can I do this in this tax year? I thought a transfer didn't count as paying in (which I understand wouldn't be permitted) but I'm not entirely sure in this situation.

Also, it might warrant a second question, but can I use both a LISA and help to buy ISA when buying a house?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to transfer a cash ISA to another provider. Note that there may be a fee for doing so. Read the terms and conditions or contact your provider to find out.

You can do the transfer at any time during the tax year, whether you have already contributed (partially or fully) or not to your ISA.

If you have £2,000 left on your S&S ISA allowance for this tax year and you transfer £1,000 from a cash ISA that you had with another provider, your £2,000 allowance stays the same.

Note that it is crucial to not close your account or withdraw the money from it. The transfer is a specific process. Contact the new provider and they'll do the transfer for you after you sign some documents.

You can only use the bonus from either the Help to Buy ISA or the Lifetime ISA to buy a house (terms apply).

Comment: You can also use the Lifetime ISA bonus when you reach 60, or if you become terminally ill with less than 12 months to live.